# Visiting Visa for Canada

Tags: visas, canada

I have visited Canada once and my visa just expired. I am applying for another visiting visa on a new passport, please what should be the appropriate answer in filling this question on the application form on the Background information page:

> 'Have you previously applied to enter or remain in Canada? No or Yes.

Does my initial visit count that I previously applied?

Comment: Curious, why would you think the answer might be 'no'?

Comment: @Boyeseun Why wouldn’t it? Getting a new passport makes no difference; you’ve still applied for and received a visa previously, they’ll have that on record along with your biometrics.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you have previously applied to enter Canada.

Yes is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is Yes, It does count. You should always mention your previous trips while applying for visa. Actually NOT mentioning or Hiding your Previous visit might even go bad for your visa application.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence, "might" in this case represents a fairly high probability.